# Avoid "rest of string" split results

Tags: python, regex, csv, split, match

I have this code to split a complicated CSV file into chunks. The hard bit is that commas may also appear within "" and thus those must not be split on. The RegEx I am using to find commas not within "" works fine:

```
comma_re = re.compile(r',(?=([^"]*""[^"]*"")*[^"]*$)')
```

Demo: [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=%2C(%3F%3D(%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%22)*%5B%5E%22%5D*%24)&test_string=Test1%2CTest2%2CTest3%2C%22%22%2CTest4%2CTest5%2CTest6%2C%22%22%2CTest7&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

```
import re

test = 'Test1,Test2,"",Test3,Test4"",Test5'
comma_re = re.compile(r',(?=([^"]*""[^"]*"")*[^"]*$)')

print comma_re.split(test)
```

Output:

```
['Test1', 'Test2,"",Test3,Test4""', 'Test2', '"",Test3,Test4""', '"",Test3,Test4""', None, 'Test5']
```

Desired:

```
['Test1', 'Test2', '"",Test3,Test4""', 'Test5']
```

How can I avoid the useless split results?

**Edit:** I didn't even know about a default CSV module, continued using that. Thanks for you efforts!

Comment: Tried a CSV module yet?

Comment: Nope not yet, the only hard part is splitting, the rest I need to do is very easy...

Comment: Parsing a csv file with a regex is such a bad idea. Just use the csv module built for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!"),(?![^",]+")|,(?=[^"]*$)
```

Will work for the example you gave, although it won't work if the input differs from that format.

```
input = 'Test1,Test2,"",Test3,Test4"",Test5'
output = re.split(r'(?<!"),(?![^",]+")|,(?=[^"]*$)', input)
print(output)

# ['Test1', 'Test2', '"",Test3,Test4""', 'Test5']
```

[Python demo](https://repl.it/C3bO)

**You should really be using a CSV parser for this**. If you can't for some reason - just do some manual string processing, going through character by character and splitting when you see a comma, unless you have recognised you are in a quoted string. Something like the following:

```
input = 'Test1,Test2,"",Test3,Test4"",Test5'

insideQuoted = False
output = []
lastIndex = 0

for i in range(0, len(input)):
    if input[i] == ',' and not insideQuoted:
        output.append(input[lastIndex: i])
        lastIndex = i + 1
    elif input[i] == '"' and i < len(input) - 1 and input[i + 1] == '"':
        insideQuoted ^= True
    elif i == len(input) - 1:
        output.append(input[lastIndex: i + 1])
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/C3bO/1)